# Get the specific category of specific location automatically

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-maps-api-2, fusedlocationproviderapi

I know that by using `getPlaceTypes()`, I can easily get the type of a place via Google Place API. But does it always give the accurate type?

Suppose I want to make an app that will use an intent service to always check my location type; so if I specify my location type to *restaurant*, it will give a notification as I enter into a restaurant (any restaurant).

I could use geofencing to do this for individual locations; but I want to avoid having to do this. Rather I want to select a location ***type*** (such as *restaurant*, *airport*, *atm*, etc) so that any location matching the type will give a notification when I enter.

Is this possible? If so, how?

I hope, I've made my question clear. Thanks in advance.